# posting on a board name which contains whitespaces in pinterest

Tags: post, whitespace, pinterest, pins

I have a code which successfully posts pins on boards which do not contain whitespace characters, such as **"mysocialboard"** . But when I try to post on boards which contain whitespace characters, such as **"my social board"**, it gives an error of board not found.
I have tried using urlencode() and urldecode() functions but they do not help.
I am using PHP in codeigniter.

Answer (score 1):

just post the board id replace the / param.
it works. though the their api document just not say

Answer (score 0):

It's not documented anywhere but while posting board name you need to replace white-space by `-` in board name. e.g. you need to do `user/board-name` instead of `user/board name`.

If you are doing it in PHP you should do...

```
str_replace(' ', '-','my social board')
```